# Accessing a full chain of attribute calls in python

Tags: python

is there a way to intercept chains of attribute calls?

What I mean is the following:

```
myobj.attr1.attr2.{...}.attrN
```

Can I somehow intercept the whole chain within myobj?

What I have in mind is a function that gets access to the full chain `'attr1.{...}.attrN'` at once, for example as a string. Is there a way to establish this?

So far, I have a rather hacky solution where **getatrr** creates novel objects whose **getattr** also creates novel objects and thereby the whole attribute chain is recorded as a string (below in fullname). But I don't like this solution at all since this has several drawbacks especially when it comes to pickling and error handling.

```
class NameCollector(object):
    ''' A helper class that resolves natural naming
    '''
    def __init__(self,myobj,name='',parent_name=''):

        self._myobj=myobj

        if name == '':
            self._fullname = ''
        elif parent_name == '':
            self._fullname = name
        else:
            self._fullname = parent_name + '.' + name

    def __getattr__(self,name):

        new_collector = NameCollector(self._myobj,name,self._fullname, self._regexp)
        if name in self._myobj._leaves:
            return self._myobj._do_stuff_with_chained_attribute_names(new_collector)

        return new_collector
```

Cheers and thanks a lot,
Robert

Comment: What is the use case for treating an attribute as a property of a *name*, rather than a property of an object referred to by that name?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to create a new object on the first access `a.b`, and then every subsequent access, just update the object's internal structure (eg. a list of values), and add a `__str__` and `__repr__` method.

```
class NameCollector(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, attr):
        self.parent = parent
        self.structure = [attr]
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in self.__dict__: return attr
        self.structure.append(attr)
        return self
    def __str__(self):
        retval = ""
        for item in self.structure:
            retval += str(getattr(self.parent, item)) + "."
        return retval[:-1] # Remove the last '.'
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr): return NameCollector(self, attr)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'other'` You must return `self` in `__getattr__`, otherwise it cannot handle chains of more than 2 attributes(try with `other.other.other`)

Comment: if attr in self.__dict__ : return attr
is probably not necessary since __getattr__ is only called if there is no match in myobj.__dict__

However, your answer does not solve my problem. If I call myobj.attr1.{...}.attr2 I'll have in return a NameCollector object that is able to print the attribute string. What I need instead is that immediately myobj has access to the full chain and can react appropriately. So myobj.attr1.{...}.attrN should directly be handled by myobj and return some data that is stored in attrN (But intermediate stages might be spelled wrong,or the user wants shortcuts).